# Website in Azure gives database connection error

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, mysql-error-1064

I just moved my MVC5 web-project to Azure. The project uses a MySql database which is now hosted in Azure as well. I have updated the connection strings, and if I start the website from localhost on my own machine (still pointing to the database on Azure) all works well. But if I start the website from my Azure url, I get an sql error.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider
>   did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. --->
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the
>   specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An
>   attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
>   permissions 127.0.0.1:3306 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateSocketStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings, IPAddress ip, Boolean unix) at
>   MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings, Boolean unix) at
>   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace --- at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace --- at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3
>   k) at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) at
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T](IQueryable`1 source,
>   String path) at
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T,TProperty](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 path) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1
>   filter) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   tripplanner.Controllers.AccountController.<Login>d__2.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult);

Hope someone can help.

UPDATE: I was using the wrong web.config file in Azure.

Comment: are you sure that you are point to the right database? 127.0.0.1:3306 is a localhost ip address

Comment: I was using a different web.config than expected. Thanks!